# Python Pandas InvalidIndexError

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I'm trying to merge some CSV files that I got as a result of some huge text files. the format is like this:

```
Key, Value
002 C000000,NY
002 D010000,11788
003  000000,N
004  000000,Y
005  000000,N
006  000000,N
007C0100,5
007C0200,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2030 PORTFOLIO
007C0300,Y
0240000,N
025D0001,0
025D0002,0
025D0003,0
025D0004,0
025D0005,0
025D0006,0
025D0007,0
025D0008,0
028A0100,10
028A0200,0
028A0300,0
028A0400,5
028B0100,28
028B0200,0
028B0300,0
028B0400,54
028C0100,1
028C0200,0
028C0300,0
028C0400,6
028D0100,20
028D0200,0
028D0300,0
```

I have a hacky approach for this and I'm not sure if the problem is with my approach (memory?) or not but here is the code for merging all these with the key, value in the same row:

```
def mergeCsv(filename1,seriesnum):
    firstfile = pd.read_csv(filename1 + "_1.csv")
    for i in xrange(2,int(seriesnum)):
        eachfile = pd.read_csv(filename1 + "_" + str(i) + ".csv")
        merged = firstfile.merge(eachfile, on='Key', left_index=False, how='inner') #also tried how='left' and how='outer'
        merged.to_csv("result.csv", index=False, na_rep='NA')
        firstfile = pd.read_csv("result.csv")
```

I get the following error after 6 csv' have joined (in this case there are 16 files)

```
  File "./parser_nsar.py", line 165, in <module>
    mergeCsv(hardcodename, 16)
  File "./parser_nsar.py", line 112, in mergeCsv
    merged = firstfile.merge(eachfile, on='Key', left_index=False, how='inner')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3632, in merge
    suffixes=suffixes, copy=copy)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 40, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 189, in get_result
    ldata, rdata = self._get_merge_data()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 284, in _get_merge_data
    copydata=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3439, in _maybe_rename_join
    to_rename = self.items.intersection(other.items)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 962, in intersection
    indexer = self.get_indexer(other.values)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1120, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

so there result I have so far is this (that is exactly what I want but for all the csvs):

```
006  000000,N,N,N,N,N,N
007C0100,1,2,3,4,5,6
007C0200,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2010 PORTFOLIO,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2015 PORTFOLIO,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2020 PORTFOLIO,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2025 PORTFOLIO,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2030 PORTFOLIO,XTF ADVISORS TRUST - ETF 2040 PLUS PORTFOLIO
007C0300,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
0240000,N,N,N,N,N,N
025D0001,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0002,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0003,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0004,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0005,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0006,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0007,0,0,0,0,0,0
025D0008,0,0,0,0,0,0
028A0100,0,472,4,49,10,30
028A0200,0,0,0,0,0,0
028A0300,0,0,0,0,0,0
028A0400,1,3,2,10,5,5
028B0100,1,302,196,107,28,93
028B0200,0,0,0,0,0,0
028B0300,0,0,0,0,0,0
028B0400,10,16,22,80,54,10
028C0100,27,0,23,10,1,23
028C0200,0,0,0,0,0,0
028C0300,0,0,0,0,0,0
028C0400,1,27,180,171,6,60
```

Comment: Not very clear what's your intended output, can you provide one?

Comment: @CTZhu Same as the output I have so far but for all the 16 csvs, it goes till the 6th one and then I have the error